# Can a tab masquerade as a space in a unicode string?

Tags: arcpy

I have some code that is intended to remove spaces from some data I'm ingesting from a group of shapefiles into a number of feature classes.  The malformed data consistently looks like this:

```
ABC12345678 90
```

and I want to make it look like:

```
ABC1234567890
```

Simple, right?  So the code block goes:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, 'FIELD') as cursor:
    for rows in cursor:
        if rows:
            firstValue = rows
            secondValue = firstValue.replace(' ', '')
            rows = secondValue[:13] #this is because some rows have more than 13 characters
            cursor.updateRow(rows)
```

I've inserted print statements and it is getting into the loop, but the .replace method is not doing anything.

I've also tried swapping out .replace() with

```
secondValue = (firstValue[:11] + firstValue[12:])
```

and no dice there either.

The print statements show:

```
[u'ABC12345678 90']
```

through the entire loop - neither replace() nor concatenation is having any effect.

Is it possible that this is not actually a space character?  Could this be a tab value or something which is causing this code to fail?

Comment: `secondValue = (firstValue[:11] + firstValue[12:])` should work although I'd take it out of the parentheses.  Better would be to use `secondValue = '{}{}'.format(firstValue[:11], firstValue[12:])`

Comment: thanks - the `'{}{}'.format()` is definitely more pythony - but alas, it does not work.  still prints out the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that the actual code you are using?  You should be getting an error in this line:

`secondValue = firstValue.replace(' ','')`

You should be getting an `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'` because your `rows` variable is a tuple returned by the Cursor, which represents a tuple of your row values.  So in the example you have, the `rows` will be:

`('ABC12345678 90',)  # this is a tuple`

Are you just trying to remove the whitespace in the value?  If so, why not just use:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, 'FIELD') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = row[0].replace(' ','')
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Aha, that did it, but it needs to be `cursor.updateRow(row)`. Thanks!  BTW, It wasn't giving me an attribute error because I have it within a `try:` loop.

Comment: That makes sense.  The problem was you were referencing the whole `row` object, which is either a list or tuple that gets returned from the cursor.  To set individual field values, you need to reference that value by the index that matches the field.

Comment: `cursor.updateRow(row)` fixed

Answer (score 0):

There are an assortment of unicode characters that look like spaces, but aren't, such as "\xa0" which is a non-breaking space. To find these, I open my data in an advanced text editor like Notepad++, and encode the data in UTF-8. If I see non-ASCII characters, I know to remove them.